# Orientdb Automatic back documentation is missing some information

Tags: orientdb, database-backups, orientdb2.2

Hi on this [page](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Automatic-Backup.html) it says:

> "exportOptions" Defines export options to use with that mode. This feature was introduced in version 2.2.

I could not find what these export options are. Can someone tell me what these options are?

I am setting up the automatic backup and would like to export the database every day at set interval. Not sure if the default export options are sufficient for my need.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it exports the full database. Use its options to disable the parts you don't need to export.

```
EXPORT DATABASE <output-file>
      [-excludeAll]
      [-includeClass=<class-name>*]
      [-excludeClass=<class-name>*]
      [-includeCluster=<cluster-name>*]
      [-excludeCluster=<cluster-name>*]
      [-includeInfo=<true|false>]
      [-includeClusterDefinitions=<true|false>]
      [-includeSchema=<true|false>]
      [-includeSecurity=<true|false>]
      [-includeRecords=<true|false>]
      [-includeIndexDefinitions=<true|false>]
      [-includeManualIndexes=<true|false>]
      [-compressionLevel=<0-9>]
      [-compressionBuffer=<bufferSize>]
```

More information on [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Export.html).